# discord.js Listening for messages in a private channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, chatbot

I am trying to listen for incoming messages in a private discord channel for discord.js v13.8, the client is not receiving any message data back for private channels. All the solutions on SO for this issue are for discord.py. This is my code.

```
client.on("messageCreate", async (msg) => {
    const title = "Parking Lot Bot"
    const desc = "Checking for parking spaces...."
    const startEmbed = fc.setStartEmbed(title, desc, "parking")
    let channel = client.channels.fetch("984498609775075359")
    .then(channel =>{
        channel.send({ embeds: [startEmbed]})
    })
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

Comment: Are you talking about direct messages when you talk about private messages?

Comment: No,I want to listen for messages contained within a private channel in a discord server from multiple users. not in a users direct private messages

Comment: Did you give your bot permission to see that specific channel? This might just be a permission issue. Make sure the bot is visible in the sidebar inside the channel

Comment: That is the issue, the bot is not inside the channel, I will take a look at the permissions again, if you know the permissions and how to set them, and would like to  answer the question and I will accept it. Thank you

Comment: @keepOnCoding You can use [Setting Up Permissions FAQ](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206029707-Setting-Up-Permissions-FAQ) by Discord and it should help you!